# Xdebug не может получить доступ к машине

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

Всем привет. Не могу настроить `Xdebug` . В офисе все работает, из дому - нет. `Log` пишет следующее:

> `Log opened at 2020-12-10 14:36:35 I: Checking remote connect back address. I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'. I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'. I: Remote address found, connecting to 192.*.*.*:9000. E: Could not connect to client. :-( Log closed at 2020-12-10 14:36:35`

При нажатии на кнопку `Validate` выдает следующую ошибку:

> The host where the debugger client is running.  In php.ini file set
> xdebug.remote_host to '192.*.*.*' or IP address of local machine
> visible from web server. See
> http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_host for more information.

Может кто сталкивался.